# Split the string in java

Tags: android, arrays, string, split

```
String items={shoporder=shop1,shopname=abc,place=mmm};
```

I want to split the items as like (shop1).And assign to another string

```
String1=shop1 
string2=abc
string3=mmm


 // Get User records from SQLite DB
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = controller.getAllUsers();
    // If users exists in SQLite DB
    if (userList.size() != 0) {
        // Set the User Array list in ListView
              final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(second.this, userList, R.layout.view_user_entry, new String[] {
                "shopId", "shopOrder","date","todayTarget","targetCompleted","shopHandled_person","shopName","salesmanName" }, new int[]
                { R.id.shopId,R.id.shopOrder,R.id.date,R.id.todayTarget,R.id.targetCompleted,R.id.shopHandled_person,R.id.shopName,R.id.salesmanName});
       final ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
         myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override

             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                 String items=myList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
}
```

The string items contains all the list values.So i want to split the values and passed in to second activity.

Comment: What is this: String items={shoporder=shop1,shopname=abc,place=mmm}; ?

Comment: `String items={shoporder=shop1,shopname=abc,place=mmm};` ? are you trying to initialize an array ? because this isn't how it is initialized.

Comment: split according to equal sign and then print the index 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to initialize `String` array is,

```
String[] items=new String[]{"shopOrder=shop1","shopname=abc","place=mmm"};
```

simpler approach would be to use `split` method of `String` to split the string on `=`.

`split` method would break your `String` in two parts, one before `=` and second after `=` signs, i.e `yourString.split("=")[0]` <- part before `=` sign, `yourString.split("=")[1]` <- part after `=` sign.

```
for (int i =0; i<items.length; i++){
    System.out.println(items[i].split("=")[1]);
}
```

**OR**

you can use `yourString.indexOf("=")+1` to find every thing after `=` sign in your string, you can then use `substring`, to print everything after `=` signs,
`substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`.

```
for (int i =0; i<items.length; i++){
    System.out.println(items[i].substring(items[i].indexOf("=")+1, items[i].length()));
}
```

**output in both cases**

```
shop1
abc
mmm
```